# Sanatize regex like input (second argument) in javascript String.replace()

Tags: javascript, regex

I would love to use the String.replace() function in JavaScript to replace a certain portion of a first string with some non deterministic user input (second string)

Example 1:

```
> var userinput = "^fancy $& regexlike stuff $/i"
> "some @@include test".replace(/@@include/, userinput)
"some ^fancy @@include regexlike stuff $/i test"
```

should be

```
> var userinput = "^fancy $& regexlike stuff $/i"
> "some @@include test".replace(/@@include/, userinput)
 "some ^fancy $& regexlike stuff $/i test"
```

Example 2:

```
> var userinput = "^fancy $& regexlike stuff $/i"
> "some @@include test".replace(/@@include/, userinput)
 "some ^fancy & test"
```

should be

```
> var userinput = "^fancy &$ regexlike stuff $/i"
> "some @@include test".replace(/@@include/, userinput)
 "some ^fancy &$ regexlike stuff $/i test"
```

**So here is the actual question:**

How do I tell String.replace() to ignore all regex syntax given in its second argument `userinput`? Is there any sanatize flag or so?

Thank you verymuch in advance!

Comment: simply escape it with back slash to consider it as a character...

Comment: well.. but I would need the user to do that or to feed the input through a custom sanatize() function first.. already thought of that, but it seems uncomfortable compared to a "isSanatized" flag on replace()

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/2593661/8767753

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the function syntax of the [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). The string returned from the function is considered as a *string*. Special characters in the string are not considered as meta-characters.

```js
var userinput = "^fancy $& regexlike stuff $/i";
var output = "some @@include test".replace(/@@include/, () => userinput);
console.log(output);
```